# Azure AD Subscription plan for SAML SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory

Can someone suggest which Azure AD subscription plan is required to use SAML SSO for custom java web applications?

On the new applications registration page in Azure AD portal, I don't find option to select SAML based login. I could see SSO only when going through -

Enterprise applications > Add New application > Non-Gallery Application

, which requires a Premium plan.

Thanks in advance,
Larsen.

Comment: It indeed needs AAD Premium.

Comment: For my use case, I will have not more than 100 users with the identity information maintained on-premises. I will have to enable Kerberos based and password based Federated SSO using Pass-through authentication. SSO protocol can be either OAuth2.0 or SAML. I was thinking if the free subscription or basic subscription should suffice this.